# Which two-dimensional array to get one-dimensional is the shortest way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]
```

how to get from this such

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

without using Array.map

Comment: [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flat()`

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
console.log(arr.flat())
```

If you don't want to use `flat()` then you can use `push()` and spread operator.

```js
const arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
const res = [];
arr.forEach(x => res.push(...x))
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(c), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) method to flatten returned arrays.

```js
let data = [
  [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]
];


console.log(data.flatMap(a => a))
```

---

Or use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to iterate and reduce into a single array.

```js
let data = [
  [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]
];


console.log(data.reduce((arr, a) => [...arr, ...a]), [])
```

Or even you can use the built-in [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method which is created for this purpose. If you want to fatten a nested array then specify the [`depth` argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Parameters) by default it would be `1`.

```js
let data = [
  [1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6],[7, 8, 9]
];


console.log(data.flat())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
let k = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]

let m = k.flat();
console.log(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array​.prototype​.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

> The `flat()` method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

```js
var arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
var res = arr.flat();
console.log(res);
```